# Distributing load in Testng

Tags: java, selenium, testng, load-testing, testng-dataprovider

If I have a dataprovider declared in testng like this:

```
@DataProvider(name = "getSuitesFromExcel", parallel = true)
    public Object[][] getSuitesFromExcel() {
        ArrayList<String> executingTestSuites = new ArrayList<String>();
        Object[][] returnObject = new Object[executingTestSuites.size()][1];
        for (int i = 0; i < executingTestSuites.size(); i++) {
            returnObject[i][0] = executingTestSuites.get(i);
        }
        return returnObject;
}


@Factory(dataprovider="getSuitesFromExcel")
  public Object[] createInstances(String s) {      
   Object[] returnObject = new Object[1];
   //Do something here
   return returnObject;
  }
```

If I want to distribute the load, like if I have 50 suites I want to run 25 in the first run and once the execution is complete I want to start the remaining 25 suites, how can I do that. I don't want to change my testng.xml, I would like to control the load inside the code itself. Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can either specify `thread-count` attribute or `threadpoolsize` attribute and control this.

Check [the documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running).